# Selenium - Firefox Profile doesn't recognize certificates

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

I need select automatically my own certificates using selenium. Aftes some studies, I found the best way is create a Firefox Profile, add Certificates and in the Selenium Webdriver "import" my Profile.

- The Real Problem: [IMG - Need Select a Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iD1R.png)

**What I trying to do?**

- Create a Profile User on Firefox
- Add my Certificate
- Selenium Imports this Profile

**Whats does happen?**

- If I open the URL that requests my certificates, it's works normally. [IMG - Open Firefox Manually has Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlHmt.png)
- If a try using Selenium Python to access the URL, Firefox doesn't recognize my Certificates. [IMG - Open Firefox by Selenium hasn't my Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Gex.png)

```
# Open My Profile
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/USERNAME/.mozilla/firefox/ri4nkdyn.default')

# Preferences that I tested
profile.set_preference("security.default_personal_cert", "Select Automatically")
profile.set_preference("security.osclientcerts.autoload", True)
profile.set_preference("security.disable_button.openCertManager", True)
profile.set_preference("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", True)
profile.set_preference("accept_untrusted_certs", True)
profile.set_preference("assume_untrusted_cert_issuer", True)

# Firefox Binary
ff_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')

# Desired Capabilities that I tested
desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
desired_capabilities["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
desired_capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True


# Create the Webdriver Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    firefox_binary=ff_binary,
    firefox_profile=profile,
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities
)
```

How I can solve this? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your firefox profile by choosing cert. or type "about:config" in the browser address bar. Verify Preference Name "security.default_personal_cert" is set to "Select Automatically" and after that use that profile for your firefox tests.